# Heuristics for boundary Harnack inequality

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, soft-question, elliptic-pde

What is the heuristic idea of the proof of the boundary Harnack inequality presented in the appendix of Caffarelli's 1998 lectures on the obstacle problem ([page 38 here](http://ins.sjtu.edu.cn/files/paper/20170525145746_obstacle-long.pdf))?

Comment: You should expand the question. People are not supposed to search for Caffarelli's lectures. You need to provide a statement of the Harnack inequality and give clear references.

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz Thank you for the heads up. Done.

Answer (score 1):

An illustration of the proof of an associated Harnack inequality for elliptic pdi is given in the book "The Maximum Principle" by Pucci and Serrin (see Chapter 7). Hopefully that helps. I can pull up paper references within if that is more helpful.

Comment: Yes, further references would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of the book, you can see the following 2 references for similar results: 
J. Serrin, ``Local behavior of solutions of quasilinear elliptic equations", Acta Math., 111, (1964), 247-302.

N.S.Trudinger ``On Harnack type inequalities and their applications to quasilinear elliptic equations.", Comm. Pure. Appl. Math., 20, (1967), 721-747.

Alternatively, a somewhat more contemporary discussion of related Harnack inequalities appears in 
A.I.Nazarov and N.N.Ural'tseva foud at https://arxiv.org/abs/1011.1888.

Hopefully that helps and sorry about the way the comment is rendered.